# Navigation bar hiding web page contents and sidebar contents in html

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I'm making a web page to try to learn HTML, CSS, PHP, and Javascript better. I've been revisiting the code trying to work out a few bugs and I discovered that my search bar is hiding the page contents and a button on my sidebar. I spent about 10 to 11 hours this week to try to fix the problem. The thing is though I'm not sure what the problem is and so I don't know which part of my code to post. All I need help with is identifying a few possible problems. If you have an idea what the problem might be I would really appreciate your help. So far none of my ideas have worked.

Here is a picture of what the page currently looks like.

[image: Here is a picture of what the page currently looks like.]

Comment: You should add the html code (where the navbar is) and the css you're using over the navbar, sidebar and search input. There can be lots of reason for this to happens, the element positions may be one of those.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add images rather as images than as links. This time I've done this for you - please see [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding a css property of `padding-top: 100px;` to the content under the header and see if that does anything?

Answer (score 0):

from the diagram it looks as if your search bar has been removed from the normal document flow.  This is usually done in CSS setting the position attribute to absolute or fixed rather than static or relative.

Check your styling for position and set it to static or relative.

Comment: I attempted that just now and sadly it didn't work. Thank you for the suggestion though.